# "RLMArray has been invalidated or the containing object has been deleted." error

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, realm

Im trying to delete a realm object which contains a realm list of objects, but when I do that I receive this error: "Thread 1: RLMArray has been invalidated or the containing object has been deleted.". I've tried all the solutions I've managed to find but none of them helped me to fix my issue. Thank you for helping in advance!

Parent object creation code :

```swift
@MainActor
    func addWordSet(name : String){
        Task {
            do {
//                let realm = try await realmService.getRealm()
                
                if let realm = realmService.getRealm() {
                    let user = realmService.getCurrentUser()
                    let set = WordSet(name: name, ownerId: user?.id ?? "")

                    try realm.write {
                        realm.add(set, update: Realm.UpdatePolicy.modified)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Child object creation code

```swift
@MainActor
    func addTranslationToSet(set : WordSet, term : String, meaning : String, completion: @escaping () -> Void){
        Task {
            do  {
                if let realm = realmService.getRealm() {
                    let user = realmService.getCurrentUser()
                    let translation = Translation(word: term, translation: meaning, ownerId: user?.id ?? "")
                    try realm.write {
                        set.translations.append(translation)
                    }
                    completion()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Parent object deletion code:

```swift
@MainActor
func deleteWordSet(set : WordSet){
    Task {
        do {
            if let realm = realmService.getRealm() {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.delete(set)
                }
            }
            
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

```swift
@MainActor
    func deleteTranslationFromSet(set : WordSet, translation : Translation, completion: @escaping () -> Void){
        Task {
            do  {
                if let realm = realmService.getRealm() {
                    let index = set.translations.firstIndex{
                        $0._id == translation._id
                    }
                    try realm.write {
                        if let index = index {
                            set.translations.remove(at: index)
                        }
                    }
                    completion()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

models code :

```swift
class Translation : Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id : ObjectId
    @Persisted var owner_id : String 
    @Persisted var word : String
    @Persisted var translation : String
    
    
    convenience init(word : String, translation: String, ownerId: String){
        self.init()
        self.word = word
        self.translation = translation
        self.owner_id = ownerId
    }
}
```

```swift
class WordSet : Object {
    
    @Persisted var name : String
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id : ObjectId
    @Persisted var owner_id : String 
    @Persisted var translations : List<Translation> 
    
    convenience init(name : String, ownerId : String){
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.owner_id = ownerId
    }
}
```

Comment: I created some models and copy/pasted your code into a project and it works perfectly. However, those models were not included in the question so I had to guess as to what they looked like. I would say the issue is either a timing issue due to the async calls and completion handlers, or the issue lies elsewhere in your code. Perhaps doing some troubleshooting and including those results and your models in the question may help.

Comment: added models snippets

Comment: Good. The models I created match identically. Since your code works correctly for me, the issue lies elsewhere in your code or possibly due to the sequence or timing of the functions in the question. One unrelated note: a Realm 'List' object can collide with a SwiftUI 'List' object so better to define it with RealmSwift like this `@Persisted var translations: RealmSwift.List<Translation>`